# How to make a multiplying program in Java using input line?

Tags: java, input, output

I tried to solve a problem on CodeChef. The problem should be multiplying two numbers. This is the script:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int test;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        test = sc.nextInt();
        while(test!=0){
            test = test - 1;
            int nummer1;
            int nummer2;
            nummer1 = sc.nextInt();
            nummer2 = sc.nextInt();
            int nummer3;
            nummer3 = nummer1 * nummer2;
            System.out.println(nummer3);
        }
    }
}
```

What my program needs to do is: first, get the amount of test cases, and then, it should multiply `nummer1` and `nummer2` to make `nummer3`. For example:
INPUT

```
2
2 3
4 6
```

And the OUTPUT:

```
6
24
```

But the whole program is giving me a runtime error (NZEC). What am I doing wrong? It gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Comment: NZEC is just too broad to help you, please post the exception message too

Comment: Sorry, it's fixed now

Comment: What exact input did you try while testing?

Comment: I don't know, it's something from a site like CodeChef. To verify if it's correct, it inputs numbers, but I don't know these since the maker of the problem only knows these, it's some kind of judge.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int test = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
while (test-- > 0) {
    String[] tmp = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    int result = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]) * Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
    System.out.println(result);
}
sc.close();
```